# Read lines from a file, grep in a second file, and output a file for each $line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have the following two files:

`sequences.txt`

```
158333741       Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_uid58167 158333741       432     1       432     COG0001 0
158339504       Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_uid58167 158339504       491     1       491     COG0002 0
379012832       Acetobacterium_woodii_DSM_1030_uid88073 379012832       430     1       430     COG0001 0
302391336       Acetohalobium_arabaticum_DSM_5501_uid51423      302391336       441     1       441     COG0003 0
311103820       Achromobacter_xylosoxidans_A8_uid59899  311103820       425     1       425     COG0004 0
332795879       Acidianus_hospitalis_W1_uid66875        332795879       369     1       369     COG0005 0
332796307       Acidianus_hospitalis_W1_uid66875        332796307       416     1       416     COG0005 0
```

`allids.txt`

```
COG0001
COG0002
COG0003
COG0004
COG0005
```

Now I want to read each line in `allids.txt`, search all lines in `sequences.txt` (specifically in column 7), and write for each `line` in `allids.txt` a file with the filename `$line`.

my approach is to use a simple grep:

```
while read line; do
  grep "$line" sequences.txt
done <allids.txt
```

but where do I incorporate the command for the output?
If there is a command that is faster, feel free to suggest!

My expected output:

`COG0001.txt`

```
158333741       Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_uid58167 158333741       432     1       432     COG0001 0
379012832       Acetobacterium_woodii_DSM_1030_uid88073 379012832       430     1       430     COG0001 0
```

`COG0002.txt`

```
158339504       Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017_uid58167 158339504       491     1       491     COG0002 0
```

`[and so on]`

Comment: Much much much faster is import in mysql, add an index and output.

Comment: mysql is too advanced for me. I am getting now familiar with 'awk'.

Comment: Do you REALLY need the allids.txt file? Unless there's some $7 values you specifically want to process while discarding the rest, why not just write each line of sequences.txt to a file named based on the $7 of each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect all you really need is:

```
awk '{print > ($7".txt")}' sequences.txt
```

That suspicion is based on your IDs file being named `allIds.txt` (note the **all**) and there being no IDs in `sequences.txt` that don't exist in `allIds.txt`.

Comment: This is probably the right solution, guessing they were using the other file as they were grepping entire lines.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite simple to do it using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$1]; next} $7 in ids{print > ($7 ".txt")}' allids.txt sequences.txt
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: I get the following error `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 NR==FNR{ids[$1]; next} $7 in ids{print > $7 >>>  ".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: yes now it works! I always love a nice `awk` oneliner!

Answer (score -2):

Extending your approach, this seemed to work:

```
while read line; do
  # touching is not necessary as pointed out by @123
  # touch "$line.txt" 
  grep "$line" sequences.txt > "$line.txt"
done <allids.txt
```

It produces text files with the required output. But I cannot comment on the efficiency of this approach.

**EDIT**:

As has been pointed out in the comments, this method is slow and would break for any file that violates the unsaid assumptions used in the answer. I'm leaving it here people to see how a quick and hacky solution could backfire.

Comment: You don't have to touch anything. Regarding `But I cannot comment on the efficiency of this approach`, running grep for every line is extremely inefficient.

Comment: It's also fragile and will break given various input values. Don't do it.

Comment: Moreover it is searching in whole line not just in 7th field so it may produce wrong results.