# reading lines in a text file with special characters specifically as quoted '<', '>' in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, scripting, special-characters

**I have a text file which is the output difference of two grepped files . the text file has lines like below* I need to read the file (loop through the lines in the text file ) and based on text to the left hand side of '<' and right hand side of '>' do something.*

editing to add details:

1. LHS of < OR RHS of >
2. if either of those, i will need to store the content into a variable, and get the 1st(ABCDEF) 3rd(10) and search (will grep) for them in one of other two files and if found print a message and attach those file(s) names in an email DL. All the file names and directories have been stored in separate variables.

how do i do that.

ps:have basic knowledge on text formatting and bash/shell commands but still learning the scripting syntax.Thanks.

```
ABCDEF,20200101,10                   <
PQRSTU,20200106,11                   <
LMNOPQ,20200101,12                   <
EFGHIJ,20200102,13                   <
KLMNOP,20200103,14                   <
STUVWX,20200104,15                   <
PQRSTU,20200105,16                   <
                                     > LMNOPQ,20200101,10
ABCDEF,20200107,17                   <
```

---

What wrong am I doing now?

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
if $line =~ ([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+\< 
    then
    IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        #echo "f1=$f1 f2=$f2 f3=$f3"
zgrep "$f1" file1 | grep "with seq $f3" || zgrep "$f1" file2 | grep "with seq $f3"
elif $line =~ \>[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+)
    then
    IFS=, read -r g1 g2 g3 <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        #echo "g1=$g1 g2=$g2 g3=$g3"
zgrep "$g1" file3 | grep "with seq $g3" || zgrep "$g1" file3 | grep "with seq $g3"        
fi
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682552/read-lines-from-a-file-grep-in-a-second-file-and-output-a-file-for-each-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+\< || $line =~ \>[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+) ]]; then
        IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "f1=$f1 f2=$f2 f3=$f3"
        # do something here with "$f1", "$f2" and "$f3"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Output:

```
f1=ABCDEF f2=20200101 f3=10
f1=PQRSTU f2=20200106 f3=11
f1=LMNOPQ f2=20200101 f3=12
f1=EFGHIJ f2=20200102 f3=13
f1=KLMNOP f2=20200103 f3=14
f1=STUVWX f2=20200104 f3=15
f1=PQRSTU f2=20200105 f3=16
f1=LMNOPQ f2=20200101 f3=10
f1=ABCDEF f2=20200107 f3=17
```

Please modify the `echo "f1=$f1 f2=$f2 f3=$f3"` line to your desired
command such as `grep`.

- The regex `([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+\<` matches a line which contains `<`
  and assigns the bash variable `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to the LHS.
  On the other hand, the regex `\>[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+)` does the similar thing for
  a line which contains `>`.
- The statement `IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` splits the bash variable
  on `,` and assigns f1, f2 and f3 to the fields.

Please note if the input file is very large, bash solution may not
be efficient in execution time. I used bash just because it will be convenient
to pass the variables to your `grep` command.

**EDIT**

Regarding the updated script in your question, please refer to the following modification:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+\< ]]; then
        IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        # echo "f1=$f1 f2=$f2 f3=$f3"
        result=$(zgrep "$f1" file1 | grep "with seq $f3" || zgrep "$f1" file2 | grep "with seq $f3")
    elif [[ $line =~ \>[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+) ]]; then
        IFS=, read -r g1 g2 g3 <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        # echo "g1=$g1 g2=$g2 g3=$g3"
        result=$(zgrep "$g1" file3 | grep "with seq $g3" || zgrep "$g1" file3 | grep "with seq $g3")
    fi
    if [[ -n $result ]]; then
        echo "result = $result"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks  @tshiono  definitely helpful, learnt usage of regular expressions from you. Will reward you for sure. Will work through my solution and get back. It's just that in my case need to process the two regular expressions (that you suggested) in separate 'if conditions'. Let me work out my sol. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. Good to know it works. Please feel free to ask me if you have questions or other requirements. BR.

Comment: added my further comment...@tshiono

Comment: based on my zgrep output in either of the files, I should be able to print something and send a email notification with a file  attachment .

Comment: 1) You need to enclose the regex test with `[[` and `]]`. 2) The `done`
statement is missing which corresponds with `do` in the 1st line. Please
take a look of my updated answer which includes these corrections. As for the
mailing function, you can solve it for yourself referring some websites such as
[this one](https://www.tecmint.com/send-email-attachment-from-linux-commandline/).

Comment: I should be able to capture the zgrepped contents in two diff variables as well. ..right...; however when I do so none is being captured . when i use a single variable, i guess last zgrepped contents override the previous contents. I am referring to "result" in your last edit.

Comment: When executing the code `if A .. elif B .. fi`, either A or B only is executed and there is no chance B overwrites the result of A. As I don't know the contents of file1, file2 and file3, I cannot debug the code for you. Please start with: 1) print out the values of f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3. 2) execute the `zgrep .. grep` pipeline with actual values given by 1).